# How do I use the iTunes Authentication Class?

Tags: php, perl, itunes

I have a PHP script that will authenticate a user.  This will grab all the reliant info for [iTunes U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/iTunes_Store#iTunes_U). The transfer script they provide is written in Perl or Java.  I would prefer to use PHP. I found an [iTunes Authentication Class](http://omega1.uww.edu/itunesu/release/1.2/itunes.phps).

I am having trouble figuring out how to actually use this to pass the authentication string to iTunes to authenticate the user with the iTunes U server.  I have the Perl version working great, except that it's static.  There is no Web interface or LDAP integration.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Where are the Java and Perl programs?

Comment: http://images.apple.com/support/itunes_u/docs/iTunes_U_Code_Samples.zip

Answer (score 1):

you can try PHP-iTunes-API. i found this API in here http://dailysyntax.com/a-really-easy-php-class-for-reading-the-itunes-api/

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak PHP, so I cannot help with the specific syntax. I did not test the instructions, they are merely derived from messing with the Perl code and reading the PHP library code.

1. Instantiate the class and set the attributes `name` (display name, e.g. *Jane Doe*), `email` (email address, e.g. *janedoe@example.edu*), `netid` (user name, e.g. *jdoe*), `userid` (user identifier, e.g. *42*), `sharedSecret` (e.g. *STRINGOFTHIRTYTWOLETTERSORDIGITS*), `siteURL` (e.g. *https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Browse/example.edu*).
2. Call the method `invokeAction` with no parameters. On success returns `true` and prints the auth response body. On failure returns `false` and prints the HTTP library error.

Ask for further support at http://omega1.uww.edu/itunesu/.